# How do I run a war as a web service locally using java and tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, tomcat6

I have some java client code that is making a connection to a web service in a war sitting on a remote server.  I'm using myeclipse 10.0, java 1.6, cxf 2.2, the embedded tomcat 6 localhost server and I'm running tomcat 6 off the command line, both tomcats are running on the same machine.

When my wsdl file points to the service on the remote server everything works fine, however, when I set up everything on my one machine, I get a java.io exception when I try to reach the service.

I setup both instances of tomcat on different ports, I can see everything loads up fine with ProcessExplorer and using netstat I can see that the ports are working with their listeners with no conflicts.  I used the information from this [link](http://archive.gria.org/docs/5.0/user-guide/installation/services/two-JVMs.html) to setup tomcat instances.  I then copied the war file over to the webapps directory and I saw that tomcat exploded the classes and loaded them.  We are also using a cacerts file for ssl authentication and I verified that it is in the correct location in the jvm.

Here is the error: Caused by: java.io.IOException: //
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2071)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2022)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1947)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:123)
    at $Proxy71.get(Unknown Source)

I'm using this url to hit the webservice endpoint:

```
http://localhost:7070/<root context>/<serviceName>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working or if there is a better way to do this?

**Aftermath:**

The war file I'm using was from a repo and added the date to it's name when I downloaded it.  I changed the name of the war to match the context root by stripping off the date, redeployed it and everything started working.

Comment: And the IOException stacktrace looks like?

Comment: Sharing the IOException's stack trace would help. You might also consider adding logging in & out interceptors on both the client & server side of the web service: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html

Comment: I'm running the SSL debugging on tomcat,unfortunately that logging is on my machine at work.

Comment: What url are you using to hit the endpoint service?

Comment: bot - Your question helped me to find the answer.  Please put it as an answer to get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The war file I'm using was from a repo which added the date to it's name when I downloaded it. When I revisited what I had done, I realized this issue, so I changed the name of the war to match the context root by stripping off the date, redeployed it and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the `war` file in the tomcat `webapps` directory and then Restart Tomcat. The `war` file will automatically be converted into the `app folder`

Comment: I left out that I had already done that part.  I added it into the question now.